# R package to extract minimal code required to reproduce a result

Tags: r, lexical-scope, reprex

A trivial example. Let's say this is the original code:

```
x = 1

y = 2

z = x * 3
```

If we specify that we want to reproduce `z`, then the package would return a new script containing only the lines of code required to generate the value `z`.

```
x = 1

z = x * 3
```

Does anyone know the name of a function or package that does this?